# Auto/Machine Learning tool to extract Category/Context from a text

Tags: machine-learning, categories

I am looking for a tool that could be trained to extract context/category from a text input.

For example, after training the tool should be able to identify that...
"Dell Inspiron Corei3 laptop Bangalore best price" is related to "Laptop" under "Computers" category
"Tata Indicom Photon plus Data Card" is related to "Data Card" under "Computers" category... and not related to "Photography"!

Thanks,
Arvind

Answer (score 0):

Something like Apache Mahout? I've never used it personally, but read about it a while ago on IBM developerworks and it looks like a fit for your problem.